# Swift generic with Any type

Tags: swift, generics

I have a such classes:

```
class Base<T> { 
}

class First:Base<Int> {
}

class Second:Base<Double> {
}
```

How can I declare type `Base` to be able to assign to it `First` object

When I try with `Any` it doesn't work:

```
class Test {

    var base:Base<Any>

    init(_ base: Base<Any>) {
        self.base = base
    }

}


Test(First())
```

It gives me:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'First' to expected argument type 'Base<Any>' (aka 'Base<protocol<>>')
```

Comment: and `Test(Base())` works..... It doesn't work with inherited classes...

Comment: But I want to use different implementations inside

Comment: Please note that `Base<Int>` is _not_ a subtype of `Base<Any>`. You cannot use `Base<Int>` on the place that expecting `Base<Any>`.

Comment: What @BryanChen said. In Swift, generics are *invariant*, not covariant. This means that they are treated as completely unrelated types – and you cannot assign one to something that expects another.

Answer (score 2):

### Simple solution

If you want `Base` to have `First` as generic type then why are you using `Any`?

This code will work

```
class Test {
    var base:Base<First> // <- this must be First instead of Any
    init(_ base: Base<First>) {
        self.base = base
    }   
}
```

### More

However if you want `Test` to accept different kinds of `Base<T>` you should declare your class like follow

```
class Test<T> {
    var base:Base<T>
    init(_ base: Base<T>) {
        self.base = base
    }
}
```

### Test

```
Test<Base<Int>>(Base())
```

> Please see the comment below by @sargeras for more ways to use my code.

Comment: that works... 
        `let test = Test(First())`
        `let test2 = Test(Second())`
        `let test3 = Test<Base<Int>>(Base())`

Comment: @sargeras: Your code does not compile in my playground. `error: cannot convert value of type 'First' to expected argument type 'Base<Any>' (aka 'Base<protocol<>>')`

Comment: I was able to compile using your code: `class Test<T> {
    var base:Base<T>
    init(_ base: Base<T>) {
        self.base = base
    }
}`

Comment: @sargeras: I understand. Thank you.